# Typescript 2.8.3: Union Types without common property

Tags: javascript, typescript

The following worked fine on Typescript `2.3.5` but it does not anymore on `2.8.3`.

```
class A {
       variableA: string;
   }
   class B {
       variableB: number;
   }
   class C {
       variableC: boolean;
   }
   type TYPES = A | B | C;

   function doStuff(types: TYPES) {
       switch (types) {
       case A: // error
           break;
       case B: // error
           break;
       case C: // error
           break;
       }
   }
   doStuff(A); // error
```

> [ts]
>   Argument of type 'typeof A' is not assignable to parameter of type 'TYPES'.
>     Type 'typeof A' is not assignable to type 'C'.
>       Property 'variableC' is missing in type 'typeof A'.

How do I change this structure so it works again?

Comment: I really don't know what you want to do here but my best guess is that you should do something like: `if(types instanceof A){...}`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`A` type designates an instance of A/B/C class, while `types` value is A/B/C class itself.

It should be:

```
   type TYPES = typeof A | typeof B | typeof C;

   function doStuff(types: TYPES) {
       switch (types) {
       case A:
           break;
       case B:
           break;
       case C:
           break;
       }
   }
   doStuff(A);
```